# where to Include '\n'?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

i am trying to get the following:

```
[A1, B1, C1]
[A2, B2, C2]
[A3, B3, C3]
```

using list comprehension.
i have gotten to this, but it only prints stuff in one line:

```
listeHoriz = ['A','B','C']
listeVert = ['1','2','3']
def generatechess ():

    return [[z+y  for z in listeHoriz ] for y in listeVert]
print(generatechess())
```

i am desperately trying to include the ’\n’ somewhere, but havnt been able to find the right position, do you know where i should put it ? (using list comprehension!)

Comment: Your code actually prints the whole variable with outer `[` and `]` and quotes  `'...'` around `A1`, `B1`, ..., is it what you want or do you exactly want the output you gave?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this in your `def` function:

```
def generatechess():
    print(*[[z+y  for z in listeHoriz ] for y in listeVert], sep = '\n')

generatechess()

['A1', 'B1', 'C1']
['A2', 'B2', 'C2']
['A3', 'B3', 'C3']
```

Incase you want to try this in Python 2.7, you must specify `from __future__ import print_function` as the first import statement inorder to use `print` as a function.

Comment: I think this is the best answer, I would keep with the return and instead do `print(*generatechess(), sep = '\n')`

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this :

```
listeHoriz = ['A','B','C']
listeVert = ['1','2','3']
def generatechess():
    combinations = [str([z+y  for z in listeHoriz ]) for y in listeVert]
    return ("\n").join(combinations)
print(generatechess())
```

or simply this :

```
listeHoriz = ['A','B','C']
listeVert = ['1','2','3']
def generatechess():
    return [str([z+y  for z in listeHoriz ]) for y in listeVert]
print("\n".join(generatechess()))
```